# Handle click event on CardView in a RecycleView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-cardview

i am trying to handle a click event for a CardView in a RecycleView but it's not working.
here is samples :

the Fragment that shows data in RecyclerView:

```
public class SearchListFragment extends Fragment{

public static final String TAG = "SearchListFragment";
View rootView;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ProListAdapter adapter;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
String url;
String prof;
ArrayList<User> pros = new ArrayList<>();

public SearchListFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Implementing View Pager
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_list, container, false);

    //RecyclerView
    recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(rootView.getContext(), 3));

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        url = getArguments().getString("url");
        prof = getArguments().getString("pro");
        sendRequest();
    }
}

private void sendRequest() {
    //Show ProgressDialog
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.loading));
    progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.dialog_wait));
    progressDialog.show();

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap();

    params.put("prof", prof);



    StringRequest jsonObjReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            //Response OK
            ....
                    adapter = new ProListAdapter(pros, getContext());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            ....
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //error
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            return params;
        }
    };

    //Adding the request to the queue along with a unique string tag
    MySingleton.getInstance(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
}
```

}

The Adapter :

```
public class ProListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProListAdapter.ViewHolder>{

private ArrayList<User> itemsData;
private Context context;

public ProListAdapter(ArrayList<User> itemsData, Context context) {
    this.itemsData = itemsData;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.pro_card, null);

    // create ViewHolder
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.nom.setText(itemsData.get(position).getName());
    holder.phone.setText(Long.toString(itemsData.get(position).getPhone()));
    holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar);

    holder.card.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.zoom_in));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return itemsData.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView nom;
    public TextView phone;
    public ImageView img;
    public CardView card;
    public LinearLayout ly;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        ly = itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.ly);
        card = itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.card_pro);
        nom = itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.pro_nom);
        phone = itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.pro_phone);
        img = itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.pro_img);
        card.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "info", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

The one item layout pro_card.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/ly"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_pro"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:cardElevation="3dp">
    <!-- Main Content View -->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pro_img"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:src="@drawable/avatar"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/pro_nom"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pro_nom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/first_names"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/pro_phone"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pro_phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/us_phones"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

nothing happen when I click on cards , what can be wrong ? I wonder if there is a clean and proper way to implement onClick in my case.

Comment: Try adding to both CardView layout `android:clickable="true"` and parent  `LinearLayout`

Comment: I did try it but still not working.

Comment: Try replacing `LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.pro_card, null);` with `LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.pro_card, parent,false);`

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try to add click listener on the linearlayout ly.setOnClickListener(this);
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The child views are consuming the touch events. To let the `CardView` take control you can override `onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)` in a custom CardView, like:

```
public class ClickableCardView extends CardView {

    public ClickableCardView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ClickableCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ClickableCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    /**
     * Intercepts touch event from child views when true is returned.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And the use your ClickableCardView in your layout file, so instead of:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>...</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

You use your new custom view (in whatever package you put it):

```
<com.company.app.ui.common.ClickableCardView>...</com.company.app.ui.common.ClickableCardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `onBindViewHolder` you can use a lambda like this:
(I haven't tested it)

```java
holder.itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener {(View v) -> {
   Toast.makeText(this, "info", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
});
```